# User Form Run-time error '424': Object required Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a user form and on a click of a button it is supposed to access or open a user form. But every time code gets to that part,

> Run-time error '424': 
>   Object required

pops up. Here is my code:

```
    If CheckSheet(TextBoxValue) = True Then
        Sheets(TextBoxValue).Select
        UserForm.Show
    Else
        Set Worksheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
        Worksheet.Name = TextBoxValue

        Dim label As Control
        For Each label In UserForm.Controls
            If TypeName(label) = "Label" Then
                With ActiveSheet
                    i = i + 1

                    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
                    .Cells(lastRow, i).Value = label.Caption
                End With
            End If
        Next

        UserForm.Show
    End If
```

Every time it gets to the part with `UserForm.Show` and `For Each label In UserForm.Controls`

I checked the spelling of the form multiple times already and it is very much the same.

Comment: Do you have "option Explicit" set?

Comment: Is it definitely spelt `UserForm`?  The first form created is usually called `UserForm1`.  Edit:  Forget that... just read the last line of your post. :)

Comment: Put a `STOP` in the first line of the code and `F8` your way through until the error occurs. That should narrow it down.

Comment: Are you using reserved words for variables? THe line `Set Worksheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))` implies (if you use `Option Explicit` as previously suggested) a line such as `Dim Worksheet as Worksheet`. While this might be fine for Java you shouldn't use reserved words in VBA for variables. Instead you should try `Set wsHydes = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))` and then `wsHydes.Name = TextBoxValue` or maybe even `wsHydes.Name = UserForm1.TextBox.Value` (with dots otherwise `TextBoxValue` is a variable).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have had something like this in mind:-

```
Sub TestCode()

    Dim Ws As Worksheet                 ' "Worksheet" is a reserved word
    Dim MyForm As UserForm1             ' "UserForm" is a reserved word
    Dim MyLabel As Control              ' "Label" is a reserved word
    Dim C As Long                       ' better name for a column than "i"

    Set MyForm = New UserForm1
    If GetSheet(Ws) Then
        For Each MyLabel In MyForm.Controls
            If TypeName(MyLabel) = "Label" Then
                With Ws                 ' true, Ws is the ActiveSheet but
                                        ' always use the same name for the same sheet
                    C = C + 1

                    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
                    .Cells(LastRow, C).Value = MyLabel.Caption
                End With
            End If
        Next
    End If
    MyForm.Show
End Sub

Private Function GetSheet(Ws As Worksheet) As Boolean
    ' return True if Ws didn't exist

    Dim Ws As Worksheet

    On Error Resume Next
    Set Ws = Worksheets(TextBoxValue)
    If Err Then                     ' Err = doesn't exist
        Set Ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
        Ws.Name = TextBoxValue
        GetSheet = True
    End If
End Function

Private Function TextBoxValue() As String
    TextBoxValue = "MySheetName"
End Function
```

In order to test if a word is a "reserved" word, select it in your VB Editor and press F1. If MS Office uses it, don't argue.

Comment: Hi, I have those codes in a different userform in a different workbook and it is working. I just copied those code from that different workbook. The only difference is that I modified the controls on the userform I am currently working on. Is it possible that my problem is with my modifications on my userform? Thank you.

Comment: Once you start using reserved words its impossible to tell the effect and often it is none. However, VBA doesn't work exactly the same way every time even if run the same version of MS Office and the same version of Windows, on the same workbook, on the same computer. Yes, it could be the modifications you made, but my (wild) guess is that you might have both workbooks, the new and the one you copied from, open at the same time. Closing one won't help. Once VBA knows where the fault is it will keep pointing to what it found.